# How do I traverse a multi dimensional NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have array made from JSON response.

`NSLog(@"%@", arrayFromString)` gives the following:

> {
>           meta =     {
>               code = 200;
>           };
>           response =     {
>               groups =         (
>                               {
>                       items =                 (
>                                               {
>                               categories =                         (
>                                                               {
>                                       icon =
>   "http://foursquare.com/img/categories/parks_outdoors/default.png";
>                                       id = 4bf58dd8d48988d163941735;

and so on...

This code

`NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[arrayFromString valueForKeyPath:@"response.groups.items"]];`

gives array with just one element that I cannot iterate through. But if I write it out using NSLog I can see all elements of it.

At the end I would like to have an array of items that I can iterate through to build a datasource for table view for my iPhone app.

How would I accomplish this?

EDIT:

I have resolved my issue by getting values from the nested array (objectAtIndex:0):

```
for(NSDictionary *ar in [[arrayFromString valueForKeyPath:@"response.groups.items"] objectAtIndex:0]) {
        NSLog(@"Array: %@", [ar objectForKey:@"name"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the data structure you get back from the JSON parser is not an array but a dictionary: `{ key = value; ... }` (curly braces).

Second, if you want to access a nested structure like the items, you need to use NSObject's `valueForKeyPath:` method. This will return an array of all items in your data structure:

```
NSLog(@"items: %@", [arrayFromString valueForKeyPath:@"response.groups.items"]);
```

Note that you will loose the notion of groups when retrieving the item objects like this.

Comment: Thanks for answer! You are right regarding your code! It logs out all items but if run this:
` NSLog(@"Items count: %d", [[arrayFromString valueForKeyPath:@"response.groups.items"] count]);`
I get 1. Why there are just one element in array when there are much more in real?

Comment: Maybe because you get an array with many elements nested in a one-element array back: ((one, two, three)) instead of (one, two, three).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JSON string you posted, response.groups.items looks to be an array containing one item, a map/dictionary containing one key, "categories."  Logging it out to a string is going to traverse the whole tree, but to access it programmatically, you have to walk the tree yourself.  Without seeing a more complete example of the JSON, it's hard to say exactly what the right thing to do is here.

EDIT:

Traversing an object graph like this is not that simple; there are multiple different approaches (depth-first, breadth-first, etc,) so it's not necessarily something for which there's going to be a simple API for you to use.  I'm not sure if this is the same JSON library that you're using, but, for instance, [this is the code](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/Classes/SBJsonStreamWriter.m) from a JSON library that does the work of generating the string that you're seeing.  As you can see, it's a bit involved -- certainly not a one-liner or anything.

You could try this, which I present without testing or warranty:

```
void __Traverse(id object, NSUInteger depth)
{
    NSMutableString* indent = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < depth; i++) [indent appendString: @"\t"];

    id nextObject = nil;

    if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@Dictionary {", indent);
        NSEnumerator* keys = [(NSDictionary*)object keyEnumerator];

        while (nextObject = [keys nextObject])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@\tKey: %@ Value: ", indent, nextObject);
            __Traverse([(NSDictionary*)object objectForKey: nextObject], depth+1);
        }
        NSLog(@"%@}", indent);
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])
    {
        NSEnumerator* objects = [(NSArray*)object objectEnumerator];
        NSLog(@"%@Array (", indent);
        while (nextObject = [objects nextObject])
        {
            __Traverse(nextObject, depth+1);
        }        
        NSLog(@"%@)", indent);
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@%@",indent, object);
    }
}

void Traverse(id object)
{
    __Traverse(object, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! I'm looking for the common method to traverse this kind of NSArray trees. Maybe some tutorial? I was unable to find any

Comment: I've edited my response with the simplest example I could come up with, along with a link to a "real" implementation of this.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code! It will defentely be useful later on some point. I have resolved my issue. Code example is in my original post.